# Voice packs in Speech settings in Windows 10 - Removing greyed out packages or is it safe to do so?

Tags: windows-10, speech

See setting attached in Windows 10.

1. Is this possible to remove via PowerShell in admin or is it safe to do so?
2. If it's ok to do so, how to remove them when they're greyed out?

---

[image: sc]

Comment: Yes;  It is safe to remove unwanted or unused voice packages.  Speech recognition is an optional feature that is supported by Windows.

Comment: I guess I didn't put that the remove button is greyed out in the UI. That was only in the title of the thread. I'll add that to the body text too.